# Where clause if true would not show at all

Tags: sql, postgresql

Have table where are two columns - `client_id, content`

every client have +- 50 content rows.

In WHERE i have this clause -  `where content NOT IN ('2','3','4')`

In result shows same clients but without rows where are **'2','3','4'**. I need if found one client with content **'2','3','4'** dont show this client completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NOT IN` only removes the rows with '2','3' or '4' in the content column.

Use `NOT EXISTS`:, the following query will return all client_id **without** '2' '3' or '4' in the content column

```
SELECT DISTINCT client_id
FROM [your table] AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 
   FROM [your table] 
   WHERE content in('2','3','4') and [your table].client_id = t.client_id)
```